# Won't return to my app after logging into FB app

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5

I apologize if this is stupid question but I just started trying to incorporate the FB SDK into my app today.

I followed the instructions online and got to the point where they suggested testing the app. The FB app opened as expected and asked permission as expected. However when I accepted the FB app stayed open instead of going back to my app.

I think it may have to do with the access token keys. I found online how to get this key, but should I enter it in the code shown below? What about the expiration date key? Or are these generated dynamically?

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"##########" andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
```

Thanks!

```
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}
```

Comment: Is it launching Safari or the FBDialog in your App? The access token and expiration date tells you if user is already logged in, thats why you get those keys from the NSUserDefaults, actually you gotta set those values into the facebook.accessToken and facebook.expirationDate and then check [facebook isSessionValid]; if it is, now you know the user is already logged in and gave permissions to you app, else you gotta make the user login, and when the user gives the permissions, you need to save the access token and expiration date somewhere if you don't want the user to login again.

Answer (score 3):

did you add the custom URL scheme to your app plist?
you need to add fb[FB_APP_ID] as a custom URL scheme
it's in their instructions